# Create a single setup step in Locust?

Tags: python-3.x, locust

Hello I am trying to do some load balance testing for a RESTful flask app I created. I am using [Locust](https://github.com/locustio/locust).

Each User spawned has a `on_start` method. I would like to create resources on the client ONCE and have each "user" task be querying for that resource.

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
    """ on_start is called when a Locust start before
        any task is scheduled
    """
    self.client.post("/resources/", json=RESOURCE_1, headers=headers_with_auth)

    @task(1)
    def profile(self):
        self.client.get("/resources/", json={})

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

This will try to create a resource for EACH user spawned. This will fail because the resource needs to be unique.

I tried:

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client.post("/resources/", json=RESOURCE_1, headers=headers_with_auth)
        super().run(args, kwargs)
```

But that also seems to run for each User. Is there a way to create a single setup step using `self.client`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked, just created my own client in setup and that is called once only when the swarm spawns

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    def setup(self):
        client = clients.HttpSession(base_url=self.host)
        client.post("/resources/", json=RESOURCE_1, headers=headers_with_auth)
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 500
    max_wait = 900
```